# How to find logic operators in string with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say logic expression looks like this:

```
(A || B) && (C | D)
```

I would like to write regular expression that searches for both `||` and `|` characters inside the expression.

This is regex I currently use to find most of the other logic operators:

```
/AND|OR|and|or|XOR|&&|<=|<|>|>=|!=|==|&|OR*|!/gi
```

So how to update currently looking `regex` to search for these two operators also?

Please note that it must be in similar form like it is now with operators divided with `|` sign (thats where my troubles come from i guess).

I tried doing it like this:

```
/AND|OR|and|or|XOR|&&|<=|<|>|>=|!=|==|&|OR*|!|\/[|]\/|\/(|)*\//gi
```

But it doesn't matches my logic expression.

Comment: Try `/AND|OR|and|or|XOR|&&|<=|<|>|>=|!=|==|&|OR*|!|\|{1,2}/gi`

Comment: Doesn't match those characters :S

Comment: [Really](https://regex101.com/r/roNJx1/1)? Please show the code, there must be a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Just tack on `|\|\||\|` and you're done

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew left few whitespaces after expresion on same online tool so it could not find mathc.. works, thanks :)

Comment: Also, you're missing some logical operators / constructs. And a fyi, just because something works doesn't mean its the best way to do it. fwiw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add an alternative branch like `|\|{1,2}` to the regex of yours:

```
/AND|OR|and|or|XOR|&&|<=|>=|<|>|!=|==|&|OR*|!|\|{1,2}/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/roNJx1/2).

The `\|{1,2}` matches 2 or 1 (since `{1,2}` is a *greedy* version of a [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), it will try to match as many `|` as it can) `|` symbols (this `|` must be escaped since otherwise, it is an [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in a regex).

If you want to enhance it (get rid of redundancy), use

```
/and|x?or|&&|[<>!=]=|[<>&!]|\|{1,2}/gi
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/roNJx1/3). Note that the words might need to be matched as whole words only, and then you'd need `/\b(?:and|x?or)\b|&&|[<>!=]=|[<>&!]|\|{1,2}/gi`.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
AND|OR|and|or|XOR|&&|<=|<|>|>=|!=|==|&|OR*|!|[||]{2}|\|
```

Also you can test out these regexes, over here: http://regexr.com/

Comment: You should read [*Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. I've updated the code. Since RegEx is eager, we should first look for the ||, then try looking for |. Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah, I just would not use the expression that a "regex is eager". It is just the unanchored alternation group that is "eager", it does not care to match the longest alternative in an NFA regex. Note that a single `|` is enough in a character class, `[||]{2}` = `[|]{2}`.

Comment: in the above regex or* valid both o and orrrrr , i think it is wrong or it should only =>or